# What kind of content can you pass to the css 'content' property?

Tags: css

I mean, besides just simple text ad eventually the use of the `attr()` function, what types of content can we 'legally' pass to the `content` css property? For example, could I pass html code?

Comment: Essentially...text or an image reference. And no, you can't put HTML in there,

Comment: Here's the spec - https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#propdef-content

Answer (score 1):

The `content` property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

CSS Syntax:

```
content: normal|none|counter|attr|string|open-quote|close-quote|no-open-quote|no-close-quote|url|initial|inherit;
```